# Is it possible to connect separate database to multiple users in wordpress?

Tags: database, wordpress

We have to create portal for hospital management so there is multiple hospital will submit there. Our question is multiple users can login but database is one we need to create multiple database but separate database only connect to one user in multiple users.

Is it possible to create?

If someone done already please tell me how to do that?

Is there any plugin to create this?

Comment: You can create something similar like that but you have to modify each user data for that, Why don't you just create different user table and push data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress config file in root (wp-config.php) defines database to use as below:

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'database_name_here' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );`
```

If login table is kept one but wp-config.php has conditional statements to define different databases based on users, then entire wordpress will subsequently use that database. 
Base your rest of the site management logic on this line. A test site with few users will show you any problems which may not be visible to us at this stage.